# preg_match_all of specific length before and after the pattern match

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching

I have a code that finds a full line that matches the pattern from a chunk of a large string.

```
$searchfor = 'some unicode words';

$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');

$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";

if(preg_match_all($pattern, $chunk, $matches)){

    echo "Found matches:\n";

    echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);

}
```

However, I don't want the full line that matches the searching words. I need that words plus 10 characters before and after the needle. Please see the following example to understand better.

SOURCE SENTENCE:

This is a very large text line I have ever seen in my life and I loveit.

NEEDLE:

I have

OUTPUT:

text line I have ever seen

( needle with 10 characters before and after it)

How to change the pattern that will support the above criteria.

TIA.

Comment: Try regex `(.{10}I have.{10})`

Comment: You only need to add capturing groups to your regex. For example `"aaa(\d{4})bbb"` will only match the 4 digits between "aaa" and "bbb".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the pattern by looking for 10 characters either side of the search string and grouping them in with the search string:

```
/^.*?(.{1,10}$pattern.{1,10}).*$/
```

Note that we use `{1,10}` rather than `{10}` because if the search string is found near the start or end of the source we may not have 10 characters available to fill the match. Here are some examples:

```
$chunk = 'This is a very large text line I have ever seen in my life and I love it.';
$searchfor = 'I have';
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
$pattern = "/^.*?(.{1,10}$pattern.{1,10}).*$/m";
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $chunk, $matches)){
    echo "Found matches:\n";
    echo implode("\n", $matches[1]) . "\n";
}
$searchfor = 'a very';
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
$pattern = "/^.*?(.{1,10}$pattern.{1,10}).*$/m";
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $chunk, $matches)){
    echo "Found matches:\n";
    echo implode("\n", $matches[1]) . "\n";
}
$searchfor = 'and I';
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
$pattern = "/^.*?(.{1,10}$pattern.{1,10}).*$/m";
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $chunk, $matches)){
    echo "Found matches:\n";
    echo implode("\n", $matches[1]) . "\n";
}
```

Output

```
Found matches:
text line I have ever seen 
Found matches: 
This is a very large tex 
Found matches: 
n my life and I love it.
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/5WA1T)